How to setup multiple No Series for Assembly Orders in Business Central?
I'm trying to setup multiple No. Series for Assembly Orders in Business Central
Here is an image showing what I want to setup:

As you can see there are multiple No. Series available to select when creating a new Assembly Order.
I've created a new No. Series called ENS-TST but as you can see it doesn't appear in the  list to select when creating the new assembly order.
How can I include my newly created No Series to the list when I create a new Assembly Order?

You can use the Relationship action available on the No. series page which will help you setup relationship between multiple No. Series and you will be able to see all the related number series in the lookup for the number series field.

